# Mostrar nombre de una lista en un bucle for

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo una serie de ejercicios y en uno me resultaría útil incluir el nombre de una lista sobre la cual itero en un bucle for.

El bucle quedaria tal que así:

```
datosReales = [mpg_float,
           cylinders_float,
           displacement_float,
           horsepower_float,
           weight_float,
           acceleration_float,
           year_float,
           origin_float]
for item in datosReales:  #DatosReales es una lista de listas.
print("La lista {} contiene {} elementos(datos).".format("item",len(item)))
```

Donde escribo "item", deberia escribir alguna función para que cuando el texto se imprimiese por pantalla no me mostrase el contenido de la lista, sino simplemente el nombre de la misma.

EJEMPLO:

La lista mpg_float contiene n elementos(datos).

Comment: La mayoría de los objetos no tienen nombre en Python.  También hay objetos con múltiples nombres.

Comment: Candid moe se contradice a si mismo. Pero a lo que el debe de referirse a que los objetos en Python pueden tener varios nombres (variables) quehacen referencia a dicho objeto. Ejemplo a=b=[] crea una lista cuyos nombres son a y b. Que hay que hacer en ese caso? Y si la lista se encuentra en un diccionario y su "nombre" es la clave de dicho diccionario? En donde buscamos el nombre? En las variables globales? Locales? En un atributo de clase? En un contenedor?

Comment: A menos que necesites obtener el valor de forma dinámica ¿Qué te impide ponerlo a mano? Al menos en el código que muestras no hay nada que te lo impida, y si estás pensando en usar una función que recibe la lista como argumento para mostrar su contenido, ¿qué te impide pasar el nombre de la lista también como argumento? No veo realmente un caso claro de uso aquí. ¿Podrías ser más específico?

Comment: @MauricioContreras, yo pensé lo mismo, pero luego vi que cada elemento de la lista es una variable (Y posiblemente sean sub listas) por lo que entiendo que desearía mostrar el nombre da cada una de esas sub listas de forma dinámica

Comment: @HeytalePazguato, sigo sin ver un caso de uso. Si construye la lista así, que cuesta usar una tupla con el objeto y su nombre?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato. La lista puede contener expresiones. Las expresiones producen objetos sin nombre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo en lo personal creo que buscar la variable donde esta guardado un objeto no es lo mas conveniente, pues conlleva los siguientes problemas:

- El objeto podria tener multiples variables referenciando a el. Cual es la correcta entonces? Como sabes que dicha variable fue usada para generar tu lista?
- Hay que buscar en todo aquello que pueda referenciar el objeto: variables locales, variables globales, variables no locales, generadores activos, clases, contenedores, etc.

Yo creo que la mejor opcion es en su lugar usar un diccionario o una clase. De ese modo restringiras la busqueda a un espacio de nombres especifico.

Ejemplo con diccionario:

```
list_dict = dict(valor1=1, valor2=2, valor3=3)

for key, value in list_dict.items():
    print(f"valor {value} encontrado en {key}")
```

Ejemplo con clases:

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self, **listas):
        #__dict__ es el diccionario interno que usa la clase para almacenar los atributos.
        self.__dict__ = listas

list_obj = Clase(valor1=1, valor2=2, valor3=3)

for attr, value in list_obj.__dict__.items():
    print(f"valor {value} encontrado en {attr}")
```

La ventaja de este segundo modo es que podes usar atributos para acceder a cada valor en lugar de corchetes y comillas como en los diccionarios.

Nota: los diccionarios garantizan el orden de insercion desde a 3.7. si tenes una version mas antigua y queres tener diccionarios ordenados, recomiendo el uso de OrderedDict del modulo collections, que mantiene el orden sin importar la version.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Al buscar información al respecto encontré que puedes utilizar el módulo [`varname`](https://pypi.org/project/varname/). Para hacerlo, solo hay que instalarlo:

```
pip install varname
```

Y este sería un ejemplo para obtener el nombre de cualquier variable

```
from varname import nameof

prueba = 'Hola!'

print(nameof(prueba))
```

Esto imprime `prueba`.

Hay otra forma para hacerlo, pero es un poco más compleja.

Si deseamos ver todas las variables globales creadas en algún programa podemos hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
print(globals())
```

Esto imprimirá un diccionario con todas las variables globales y símbolos del programa actual, por ejemplo, al utilizar el siguiente código desde una celda de `Jupyter Lab` (Pero tendrías que adaptarlo en caso de que las variables sean atributos de una función o clase ya que estarían dentro de las variables locales de dicha función o clase).

```
prueba = 'Hola!'

print(globals())
```

Devuelve lo siguiente:

```
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': 'Automatically created module for IPython interactive environment', '__package__': None, '__loader__': None, '__spec__': None, '__builtin__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '_ih': ['', "prueba = 'Hola!'\n\nprint(globals())"], '_oh': {}, '_dh': [WindowsPath('C:/Users/jecs9/Documents/JupyterLab')], 'In': ['', "prueba = 'Hola!'\n\nprint(globals())"], 'Out': {}, 'get_ipython': <bound method InteractiveShell.get_ipython of <ipykernel.zmqshell.ZMQInteractiveShell object at 0x000002078BCE0880>>, 'exit': <IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall object at 0x000002078BCE0F10>, 'quit': <IPython.core.autocall.ZMQExitAutocall object at 0x000002078BCE0F10>, '_': '', '__': '', '___': '', '_i': '', '_ii': '', '_iii': '', '_i1': "prueba = 'Hola!'\n\nprint(globals())", 'prueba': 'Hola!'}
```

Como podemos ver, al final está nuestra variable `prueba`. Al ser un diccionario, podemos obtener únicamente las llaves (Que serían los nombres de las variables) al utilizar `globals().keys()`.

Ahora, para obtener el nombre de alguna variable podemos buscar esa variable en las llaves de nuestro diccionario y cuando coincida entonces devolver ese nombre:

```
def get_var_name(variable):
    for name in globals().keys():
        if eval(name) == variable:
            return name
```

---

**Nota:** La función `get_var_name()` contiene la función especial `eval()` que  interpreta y ejecuta lo que contenga literalmente como código de `Python` por lo que podría ser un riesgo o vulnerabilidad en el programa, por ejemplo, la siguiente línea:

```
eval('print("peligro")')
```

Imprime `peligro`. Pero por ejemplo podría ejecutar otros scripts, etc...

---

Como no pusiste el código completo convertí en `string` todas las variables adentro de tu lista para ejemplificar el uso de la función:

```
def get_var_name(variable):
    for name in globals().keys():
        if eval(name) == variable:
            return name

datosReales = ['mpg_float',
           'cylinders_float',
           'displacement_float',
           'horsepower_float',
           'weight_float',
           'acceleration_float',
           'year_float',
           'origin_float']

print('La lista <{}> contiene {} elementos (datos).'.format(get_var_name(datosReales),len(datosReales)))
```

Esto imprime:

```
La lista <datosReales> contiene 8 elementos (datos).
```

### Edición

Gracias al comentario de @DanteS. modifiqué la función para quitar el `eval` y eliminar el riesgo:

```
def get_var_name(variable):
    for name, value in globals().items():
        if value is variable:
            return name
```

Comment: Yo iteraria sobre los globals().items() que te devuelve en el for una tupla con el nombre de la variable y el valor. Luego usaria el operador is para saber si el valor ES el buscado. Ten en cuenta que dos cadenas pueden ser iguales, pero no ser la misma. Ademas, te evitas el eval.

Comment: Ademas, ese segundo caso no funcionaria si se espera conocer una variable local que contenga el objeto, ya que solo busca en las variables globales.

Comment: @DanteS. Ah muy bien! Al utilizar el valor de la llave ya no tengo que utilizar `eval`, ahora edito la respuesta. En cuanto al segundo comentario, es correcto, por eso intenté explicar que si se desea buscar adentro de una función o clase tendría que modificarlo ya que esa variable no se encontrará en las globales.